# Janusgraph delete vertex and commit completes but next operation still sees the vertex

Tags: cassandra, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I have a piece of code which deletes a vertex and commits the transaction.
The next operation still sees the vertex for some reason.
Its also strange that it only sees it sometimes may be based on timing etc.
e.g. graph
service--contains-->route

operation 1: deletes contains edge and delete vertex and commit

operation 2: get contains edge from service node and it still gets the route node which was deleted in operation 1

The 2 operations are one after the other and not run in parallel so there is no issue of reading it before 1st commit.

Also if 1st commit is completed successfully then my understanding is that all other threads should immediately see the updates.

using janusgraph api for java with cassandra db

sample pseudo code:

```
synchronized methodA:
 do some operations
 figure out route X need to be deleted from graph
 get all routes using contains edge from service node
 // service---contains--> route
 get route X from all routes 
 singlethreadExecutor.submitTask(DeleteRoute X)
 update some other DB with service without route X

Task DeleteRoute (route x)
 get  route X from graph DB
 delete route X vertex 
 commit

Operation1 calls into methodA:
 service with 4 routes R1,R2, R3, R4
 Expected to delete R3
 Works as expected
 R3 is deleted from graph as well as other DB

Operation2 calls into methodA:
 service expected routes in graph with R1, R2, R4
 however, method A still gets all 4 routes including R3 which is deleted in operation 1
```

Please note method A is synchronized so operation1 and 2 do not collide with each other.
operation1 is complete and then operation 2 is started

This is puzzling to me especially when my logs indicates commit completed for operation 1 and operation 2 still gets the route node R3 from graph using janusgraph api.

We are not using threaded transaction
We are not using new transaction
We rely on tinkerpop opening new transaction with first operation for the thread.

log snippets:

Operation 1:

2019-06-17 14:58:25,213 | deleteNode : route:1560307936368:1683669533 
2019-06-17 14:58:25,216 | commit
2019-06-17 14:58:25,350 | Time Taken in commit = 133

Operation 2:

2019-06-17 14:58:25,738 | updateNode
2019-06-17 14:58:25,739 | updateNode Node to be updated:  route:1560307936368:1683669533
2019-06-17 14:58:25,740 | updateVertex: vertex updated for key: route:1560307936368:1683669533
2019-06-17 14:58:25,741 | updateNode Time Taken in updateNode =  3

As you can see Operation 1 deletes the route node and commits and operation 2 when it reads from graph, still gets the same route node and was able to update it.
Our update api check if the vertex is present before updating it and throws error if its not present.

So clearly the vertex is still returned from graph using janusgraph getVertex api based on node id key even if the delete was success and commit was complete just before it.

The same code works as expected if the time difference between the 2 operations is manipulated to be more than couple of minutes.

We also have configured to use janushgraph cache.

With all of this give, I am really puzzled how is this even happening.

I can understand if the 2 operations are somehow running in parallel and step on each other and race conditions can give me stale data but the operations are synchronized and happen one after the other.

expected to not return the vertex in 2nd operation after its deleted and commited in 1st operation especially when both the operations are synchronized and happen one after the other without any failures/exceptions.

---

**Use case 1:**

Thread-1 ----calls---> synchronized method-1---> get edge/vertex, update vertex, commit ----submits ---> singleThreadedExecutorTask ---> delete edge/vertex, commit ----> calls --> synchronized method-1 (for operation 2) **----> here the get edge/vertex still gets the old edge/vertex**

I can understand use case 2 where transaction scope is for the thread with first operation and anything committed in other threads is not visible in this transaction scope, so I have to ideally commit transaction before starting operation 2 to see the changes.

**I tried this for the Use case 2 and it works as expected !!**

---

**Use case 2:**

Thread-1 ----calls---> synchronized method-1---> get edge/vertex, update vertex, commit ----submits ---> singleThreadedExecutorTask ---> delete edge/vertex, commit ----> Thread-1 Completes.

***After around one minute:***

Thread-2 ----calls---> synchronized method-1---> get edge/vertex, update vertex, commit ----submits ---> singleThreadedExecutorTask ---> delete edge/vertex, 
commit ----> Thread-2 Completes.

Problem Thread-2 call into synchronized method-1 still gets the old edge/vertex which is deleted as part of Thread-1 process.

Now in this case.

Thread-1 scoped transaction is opened with first graph operation and that transaction gets closed immediately after update.
After that singleThreadedExecutor task is run in separate thread so, it opens its own new transaction for 1st operation and closes the transaction with commit when task is finished.

Thread-2 when it starts after a minute opens its own thread scoped transaction with 1st graph operation - this get operation in this new thread transaction scope should be able to get the correct data without deleted edge/vertex from thread 1 especially considering ti starts almost after 1 minute.
This is not even a clustered set up.
And even with clustered set up - i thought quorum has to be satisfied before the commit calls can return and rest of the replication can happen independently (delayed)

This is the part I am not able to understand, of course if I add manual intervention with 2 threads like starting thread 1 may be after 2 minutes, it works for some reason.

2 minute seems to be really long for eventual consistency in this case.

So whats the option for the application to handle this?

Is there any way to force the graph operation to wait for eventual consistency?
Like thread-2 i can specify the first get operation has to wait unless it returns consistent data by resolving all conflicts etc.

I dont think opening new transaction in thread 2 or trying to do some sort of global commit to close previous stale transaction opened if any is the right way to do it as this is just the start of new thread.

---

Answer (score 4):

**Mutations to Cassandra do not show up instantly**

Cassandra is what's known as an eventually-consistent database, this means that changes that are written to it are not guaranteed to be immediately visible to all consumers. It makes a best effort to make it happen, but this does not always end up happening. The point is, you should not expect to see any mutations written in Cassandra immediately after they are written.

When a write to Cassandra is completed, it still needs to propagate the change to the rest of the cluster. It is entirely possible for a read that occurs immediately after the mutation is picking up some stale data.

**JanusGraph's Locking and Synchronization is independent of Cassandra's Consistency**

JanusGraph is ensuring that it is firing off only one call to Cassandra at a time, but this does not get around the fact that after Janus' call to Cassandra is complete, there is still a period of time while Cassandra is propagating the mutations; if the next call to Cassandra that Janus makes is before that mutation is complete, the data will be stale.

**The General Recommendation is to do App-side Checking**

Using an eventually-consistent storage backend will result in these kinds of issues; the recommended initial path to take for this from the [JanusGraph Documentation on Eventually Consistent Backends](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/eventual-consistency.html) is to resolve such inconsistencies in your application, when reading. Architect your app in a way that it does not assume that a mutation call returning means that the mutation will be visible, if you can.

In your example, I would insert something between your two transactions that either waits an appropriate amount of time (I'd say even just a few seconds should be plenty of time), or that checks that the delete completed.

**But, Cassandra is not a good solution if you need strong data consistency**

I would note that while the previous paragraph is a quick and easy way of checking this, if you find that you absolutely need to confirm every upsert and delete operation, you might be better off using a different storage backend, such as HBase or BerkeleyDB. [Here is the list of options for storage backends according to the JanusGraph Manual](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/storage-backends.html).

But if you're generally okay with a lack of strong consistency, the upside is that Cassandra tends to scale horizontally fairly easily. In the end, it all depends on the needs of your app.

Comment: Thank you Rebecca, I appreciate the response and detailed info. I understand Cassandra eventual consistency may take a few seconds but I expected Janusgraph cache to take care of such cases especially for the reads.  In this example, service----contains--->route edge is deleted and route vertex is also deleted. But may be delete is a special case where edge and vertex is removed/marked expired from the cache and the next read forces it to go to Cassandra which may be not consistent yet.

Comment: Also I thought commit should only return when all clusters/quorums are satisfied for the write.  Now even if Cassandra mutations may take a few seconds , eventually some layer has to consider the writes and accordingly return the correct data. Either based on jansugraph cache or Cassandra cache. Not sure of cassandra by default supports the in memory cache to support such delayed writes/mutations delay etc. But I understand that temporary inconsistencies are expected as per Janusgraph documentation and applications need to be aware and handle it accordingly as needed

Comment: Another interesting use case failure for the same example: Thread1 ---> gets into synchronized method 1 ---> graph get edge/vertex, update, commit ---> calls into singleThreadExecutor ---> graph delete edge/vertex, commit --->returns to Thread 1 --> Thread 1 finishes.  Now after 1 minute Thread 2 starts and goes through the exact same process as Thread 1 and the first get edge/vertex fails here with same problem, it still gets the vertex/edge whihc was deleted through Thread 1 operations. Thread 1 commits everything and still same issue after 1 minute of thread 1 finishing,added both use cases